Can't link to C library despite explicit command in build.rs
I am trying to link a library against a local build of arpack. I have compiled arpack itself and I have it as a static binary. I then make this build.rs
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    // Get the path to the directory containing the Cargo.toml file (workspace root)
    let workspace_root =
        env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").expect("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR not set");

    // Define the path to the directory containing the native libraries relative to the workspace root
    let lib_path = Path::new(&workspace_root).join("arpack-ng/build/");

    println!("cargo:warning={}", lib_path.display());

    // Print the instructions for Cargo to find the native libraries
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", lib_path.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=arpack");
}

This fails with this error:
 = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/algebra/target/debug/deps/algebra-8ab0fc9a1c48e81c.8q7c32k90oqy6djs87syi3nmg.rcgu.o: in function `algebra::eigen_decomposition::faer_arpack_symmetric_f64':
          /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/algebra/src/eigen_decomposition.rs:150:(.text._ZN7algebra19eigen_decomposition25faer_arpack_symmetric_f6417h42c779a97fe8f680E+0xa27): undefined reference to `dsaupd_c'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/algebra/src/eigen_decomposition.rs:199:(.text._ZN7algebra19eigen_decomposition25faer_arpack_symmetric_f6417h42c779a97fe8f680E+0x2b7d): undefined reference to `dseupd_c'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

 = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-link-lib)

The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: algebra@0.1.0: /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/algebra/arpack-ng/build/


I have compiled arpack, the file libarpack.a exists under the path  /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/algebra/arpack-ng/build/. So the library exists, and the build.rs is pointing to the correct location, why is cargo not linking it?
I followed advice int he comments and tried inspecting what symbols are in the library through:
nm libarpack.a | grep dsaupd_c

They don't exist, however dsaupd_ does exist. Recompiling arpack enabling ICB does seem to define the symbols, however, I seem to be missing symbols from libgfortran

I would check that the built arpack library has the symbols first: nm libarpack.a | grep dsaupd_c

Will be hard to debug for us without being reproducible on our machines ...
Maybe reproduce your issue in an open git repository with everything checked in, including the compiled c library. Then go to the Rust discord or Rust subreddit and ask if somebody can look over it with you. This question might be too big for SO.

Note that static libraries don't include their own dependencies, so you need to add cargo:rustc-link-lib directives for all libarpack dependencies too, not just arpack itself.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I trie dit, something is fishy there. I updated my post.

@Jmb How could I find all linking dependencies of libarpack?

@Makogan from their documentation, I assume. Given that it's apparently written in Fortran, you will need at least the version of libgfortran with which it was compiled.

Running ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarpack.so.2 on my machine lists the following dependencies: liblapack.so.3, libblas.so.3, libgfortran.so.5, libquadmath.so.0, libatlas.so.3 and libz.so.1 in addition to the usual libc stuff.
